# pdf.js viewer extension is laggy

Tags: javascript, svg, pdf.js, reflow, object-tag

I extended the `pdf.js` viewer so that I can "insert `.svgs` into the `.pdf`".

That means, I just inserted an extra `imageWrapper` into each page `div` and added `.svgs` as `objects` inside. The result looks like the `.svgs` are inside the `.pdf`, although they are just part of the viewer, of course.

For those not familiar: [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) you can find a demo of the viewer; just inspect a .pdf-page and you will understand my explanation.

**However, if I just scroll up/down, the viewer is quite unresponsive and laggy whenever `.svgs` are near the viewport.** It may be relevant to add that this behaviour doesn't show up if I insert videos or images. Additionally, the `.svgs` are quite big (3x around 3MB), but if I have these inside a plain `html`-website with some blindtext, scrolling isn't a problem at all.

To me it rather seems like this is some kind of **layout thrashing** issue. Nevertheless I wasn't really able to track down the cause(s):

The performance tool from Chrome pointed me towards the [`ui_utils.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/ui_utils.js) file and in particular this code snippet:

```
function watchScroll(viewAreaElement, callback) {
  let debounceScroll = function(evt) {
    if (rAF) {
      return;
    }
    // schedule an invocation of scroll for next animation frame.
    rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame(function viewAreaElementScrolled() {
      rAF = null;

      let currentX = viewAreaElement.scrollLeft;
      let lastX = state.lastX;
      if (currentX !== lastX) {
        state.right = currentX > lastX;
      }
      state.lastX = currentX;
      let currentY = viewAreaElement.scrollTop;
      let lastY = state.lastY;
      if (currentY !== lastY) {
        state.down = currentY > lastY;
      }
      state.lastY = currentY;
      callback(state);
    });
  };

  let state = {
    right: true,
    down: true,
    lastX: viewAreaElement.scrollLeft,
    lastY: viewAreaElement.scrollTop,
    _eventHandler: debounceScroll,
  };

  let rAF = null;
  viewAreaElement.addEventListener('scroll', debounceScroll, true);
  return state;
}
```

This made sense to me as commands like `scrollLeft` trigger reflow, but commenting out the part with `currentX` and `currentY` didn't change the behaviour noticably.

I would appreciate any tips on solving this problem and especially some explanation on the **scrolling behaviour of `pdf.js`** very much.

**EDIT**: In the meantime I have come to the conclusion that this might just be an garbage collection problem. Maybe hiding the `.svgs` helps.